# Не работает предпросмотр PDF файлов в Visual Studio Code (VScode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, pdf, latex

Я использую VScode для работы с LaTeX, на Windows (с помощью WSL). Недавно возникла проблема, что перестал работать предпросмотр PDF в отдельном окне, а именно не загружается вообще, при этом сам PDF файл нормально открывается через стороннее приложение, то есть проблемы с компиляцией самого Теха, скорее всего, нет.

[image: Пример проблемы]

Я попробовал установить другое расширение для отображение PDF файлов, которое начало справляться со своей задачей. Однако у него есть ряд недостатков (медленно подгружается после рекомпиляции, не позволяет переходить к конкретным местам кода и т.д.). Из-за чего хотелось бы починить старое расширение.

[image: По умолчанию сейчас выбрано не стандартное расширение.]

Из-за чего возникла эта проблема, я не могу сказать точно, так как появилась совершенно без какой-либо причины.

Версия VScode:

```
Версия: 1.77.3 (user setup)
Фиксация: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Дата: 2023-04-12T09:16:02.548Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Изолированные: No
```

Версия LaTeX Workshop: 9.8.2

Надеюсь на помощь, так как не знаю что делать.

По моему запросу я нашёл этот ответ: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527463/pdf-preview-in-visual-studio-code, однако он мне не помог.

Comment: Вы можете добавить своё решение как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**: Нашёл на Reddit решение [проблемы](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/ies1n9/latex_workshop_pdf_viewer_in_wsl/).

**TL;DR** Зайдите в свой проект и нажмите (по умолчанию) сочетание клавиш `ctrl + alt + v`, тогда ваш PDF файл откроется в браузере, что поможет решить эту проблему.